# Css position relative or absolute variable height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been trying to align the "Low" text and arrow that I showed on image. Basically want I is to align the text and the arrow (Low) some pixels below the blue chart. i.e. chart 3.

I'm generating those blue bars from my database and creating a table. Here is the code:

```
.lower { 
    display: block; 
    font-size:7pt; 
    color:#666666; 
    position:relative; 
    bottom: 5px; 
    left:-25px;
}

<td valign="bottom" style="width:8px;height:20px;"
    <div style="padding: 0px;width:8px;height:" . round($var/2.5) . "px;background-position:bottom;background-repeat:no-repeat; display: block;">
        <div class="lower" >Low <img src="icon-sort-up.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

The round(`$var/2.5`) that one calculates my high to align my "High" text and arrow but somehow is affecting my Low text.

[a busy cat http://sandbox.visistat.com/partner-reports/live3/pulse.png](http://sandbox.visistat.com/partner-reports/live3/pulse.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting your "lower"  div into your "high" div, that is why the round($var/2.5) is also affecting your "lower" div. Since the round($var/2.5) is written inline instead of in a seperate CSS file it will disregard anything that was in your css file and take the inline style instead.

To prevent this you can either place the "lower" div below the first div instead of nesting inside it.

Also you are not closing your opening td tag in your code example, although that might be a typo.